# Large files upload issue in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a async method for upload files. In my `web.config` I already set up `maxcontentlength`.

But I can't upload file larger than 15mb. It gave me an error `err_connection_reset`.
My hosting also supports max 1gb file uploading and 90sec execution timeout.

Here is my code sample.

```
[NoAsyncTimeout]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Videos video)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (video.CategoryId > 0)
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Server.ScriptTimeout = 9001;
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                    // ... other operations
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string error = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `web.config` attributes. I also tried to make maximum execution timeout.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1073741824" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
 <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. It was about `enabling 32 bit applications` from hosting panel.

Comment: Strange - do you know why is it required to do large uploads?

Comment: Maybe because of ISAPI filters. But have no idea about anything else. I just tried and it fixed my problem. But since at that time my all other projects also having problems because of that. And now all are good.